# What is the Alternative for elevation attribute in HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am building a HarmonyOS application, Where I need to set elevation on custom component.

In Android we can set elevation on and widget as follow

```
android:elevation="8dp"
```

but, I saw in HMOS there is no any elevation attribute present for view.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback, as confirmed by the team, The Java UI is not currently supported, Please stay tuned on HarmonyOS official websites.

For JS UI, you may can refer to [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/js-components-common-styles-0000001050791158).

Answer (score 0):

Harmony has **setAltitude** API available from SDK 6, unfortunately which is not released to public yet.